# Vitest visualViewport is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vitest

I am writing one of my first vitest and my code does a test of the `visualViewport` when the component is mounted. When I run the test, it fails because the `visualViewport` is not defined. How would I go about having this defined when the test runs?

```
onMounted(() => {
  if (visualViewport.width > 1024) {
    options.isDesktop = true;
  }

  visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', ({target}) => {
    if (target.width > 1024) {
      options.isDesktop = true;
    } else {
      options.isDesktop = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```
ReferenceError: visualViewport is not defined
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │ ❯ src/scripts/search-and-filter/App.vue:22:3
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │     20| 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │     21| onMounted(() => {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │     22|   if (visualViewport.width > 1024) {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │       |   ^
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │     23|     options.isDesktop = true;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     │     24|   }
```

Let me know if more information is needed and I will add it. Thank you for your help.

`jsdom` is being used so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: First, I wonder why you use the `visualViewport` api to detect the device. This should be done with `window.innerWidth` to get the Lay-out width.  In tests you need to set the value before. Like `window.innerWidth = 1024` and reset it afterwards you can use `afterEach` to set it to the default value

Comment: If you want to keep the visual viewport, you need to set the values you need or create a global mock for the visual viewport. I guess jsdom has it not implemented: https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#globals